# change paypal configuration per request

Tags: node.js, express, paypal-sandbox, multi-tenant, paypal-rest-sdk

I want to use the paypal-rest-sdk for payments in a multi tenant  node/express application. Before I can fire a request, I have to configure the paypal module.

```
  paypal.configure({
    'mode': "sandbox",
    'client_id': "XXXXXXXXXXX",
    'client_secret': "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
  });
```

But they just provide a way to configure the paypal module globally. 
I didn't find anything about changing the configuration on each request in my node/express app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can read how to do it directly in their documentation :

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/blob/master/samples/configuration/multiple_config.js

Seems like you can pass a new configuration object as second parameter to override the global config :

```
var second_config = {
    'mode': 'sandbox',
    'client_id': '<SECOND_CLIENT_ID>',
    'client_secret': '<SECOND_CLIENT_SECRET>'
};

paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, second_config, function (error, payment) {

});
```

Comment: does this also mean, that the first configuration will be used if the second one is incorrectly configured ? or can I just leave the global configuration out ?

Comment: don't know about that, but I guess they will throw an error if something is incorrectly configured, hope so.